# Extracting encoded features after CatBoost

Tags: classification, categorical-data, boosting

I have a dataset containing numerical as well as categorical variables.

After I've fit my dataset to a CatBoostClassifier, I want to extract the entire feature set, with the categorical variables encoded in whatever method the classifier decided to encode them.

How can I extract the fully transformed (encoded) features? (similar to what a fit_transform method would return)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, CatBoost does target encoding per split, so you end up with different values of encoding at different trees.

> Before each split is selected in the tree (see Choosing the tree
> structure), categorical features are transformed to numerical. This is
> done using various statistics on combinations of categorical features
> and combinations of categorical and numerical features.

https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic.html

However, if you just want to use the CatBoost encoding algorithm. You can use [CatBoostEncoder](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/catboost.html)